# Fragment Activity goes null when another fragment is added

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

i was using the compatibility library android.cupport-v4.jar that android is giving, i found an issue, i started building a TabActivity that contained several fragments into it's tabs.

I have a starting tab that has a GridView, from the listener of the item in the adapter i call the following code:

```
FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
ft.add(R.id.relativeLayoutContent, newFragment);
//        ft.replace(R.id.relativeLayoutContent, newFragment);
ft.addToBackStack(null);
ft.commit();
```

The issue is when i open the new Fragment and go back to the first one, it doesn't go for the onAttach, cause it was never de-attached, and since the new Fragment was, the activity is now holding the last one, but not the first one, if i try to click an element again, it will crash telling me that the getActivity method from the Fragment is null.

Any workaround on this?

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure what you are trying to accomplish but I am going to take a stab at it anyways.

You should  use the fragmentmanager to hold your different fragments but when you use the add method in FragmentTransaction, assign your fragments a tag so you can easily switch back and forth between fragments.

The TabActivity has also been deprecated.
Have you thought about using Tabs in the ActionBar?
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Tabs

Here is a snippet I pulled from something I am currently working on:

```
public void changeFragment(String tag){

    Fragment tmpFragment;
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    //look to see if we have already added the fragment
    tmpFragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tag);

    //we currently have a fragment, hide it
    if (currentFragment != null){
       fragmentTransaction.detach(currentFragment);
    }

    //did not find the fragment
    if (tmpFragment == null){
      if (tag.equals("map")){
         currentFragment = CustomMapFragment.newInstance();
      } else if (tag.equals("list")){
        currentFragment = ListFragment.newInstance();
      }else {
        //TODO
    }
    //add fragment for 1st time
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.content_frame, currentFragment, tag); 
  } else {
    //we found the fragment
    currentFragment = tmpFragment;
    fragmentTransaction.attach(currentFragment);  //show the fragment we found
  }
  fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

You can use this methods to switch between fragments based on their tag.